# Can't separate Ascii symbol from hyperlink

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I'm currently displaying my recent posts in WordPress with the below script, but I can't get the ASCII symbol to be apart from the hyperlink.

If I hover on a recent post then I see that the ASCII symbol is also part of the hyperlink.

```
<ul>
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '2' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="'.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a>&gt;</li> ';}    
?>
</ul>
```

How can I have it to be like this:

[Recent post 1](http://example.com/recentpost1) > 
[Recent post 2](http://example.com/recentpost2) >

Instead of:
[Recent post 1>](http://example.com/recentpost1)  
[Recent post 2>](http://example.com/recentpost2)

Comment: According to the code you've shared - it should be as you wish it would be.
Can you provide a link to the blog?

Comment: Excuse me I work in local development, so I don't have a live example.
But it is solved by the answer of Bhavik Shah. Thanks

Comment: if my answer has helped you, please consider to accept it.

Comment: try my latest answer. I have modified it little. Check if it can solve  your problem completely.

Comment: Totally solved, Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to follow KISS principle: try this

```
<ul>
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '2' );

// get two most recent posts using wp_get_recent_posts()
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

// loop through both the posts
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){

    // get permanent link from id using get_permalink()
    $permalink = get_permalink($recent["ID"]);

    // esc_attr is basically used for escaping the output
    $title = esc_attr($recent["post_title"]);

    // finally, echo the output
    echo "<li><a href='$permalink' title='$title'>".$recent['post_title']."</a>&gt;</li>";
}    
?>
</ul>
```

Refer [**`wp_get_recent_posts`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts), [**`get_permalink`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) and [**`esc_attr`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr) on official documentation site for detailed information.

Edit: *amended the answer after Ofir Baruch's comment.*

Comment: I don't think that having output between `<li>`s elements is semantically correct (and also valid html).

Comment: @OfirBaruch: Sorry, but i didn't got your point. What do you mean?

Comment: @ Bhavik Shah, Solved. Thank you!

Comment: `<li>XXX</li>YYYY<li>XXXX</li>`. I think that having output between `li` elements is not valid. (`YYYy`)

Comment: A better solution might be using the `:after` css pseudo-code.

Comment: Although it's ' solved' , I get the ascii symbol at a new horizontal link. so I now see: Recent post 1 <br>
>
Validation error: Text not allowed in element ul in this context.

How to solve?

Comment: @OfirBaruch: `:after` is not supported in all browsers like IE7. Along with that, i would also mention here that you are right. I will correct the answer

Comment: These days it completely fine to ignore IE7 (which has less than 1% of usage around the world) and by the way who ever still use IE7 deserve to suffer.

Comment: Do you also know how to apply the same principle with <ul><?php wp_list_categories('title_li&show_count=1');?></ul> Or shall I raise a new question?

Comment: @ Ofir Burach, I agree. People please stop supporting IE7